# Eliminate double entries in an array and sort the result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an app which is retrieving its information from a plist. 
The `plist` is an array of `Dictionaries` with the keys (author, cat, content). 
Now I would like to show the categories in a table. 
So I need all unique category entries in a sorted way.

I have successfully implemented following way but I am interested if this is the "right" solution.

1. Go through plist array and make new `NSMutableArray` with all category
   entries of the dictionary
2. put this `NSMutableArray` into a `NSSet` to get unique Elements
3. put this `NSSet` into an `NSArray` to have the possibility to sort it.
4. return a `NSMutableArray` initiated with the sorted `NSArray`

I feel not , that this is the right way of doing so. 
Any suggestions to do it better ?

Thanks a lot!

```
//InhaltefromWEb is a NSMutableArray
-(NSArray*) getCategories {
NSMutableArray* categorieTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

unsigned count = [InhalteFromWeb count];
while (count--) {
    NSString *tempString;
    tempString=[[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:CATEGORY];
    NSLog(@"tempString %@", tempString );
    [categorieTemp addObject:tempString];
}

NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:categorieTemp];
NSLog(@"categories from engine %@", categorieTemp);
NSArray* tempAr = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueElements allObjects]]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

return  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempAr];

}
```

Comment: yeah, that's fine.  You could just use an NSMutableSet instead of category temp in your while loop and just add the strings directly to it.

Comment: good hint :-) thank you. I am still lost with all these different types and possibilities to store data and then to reconvert. :-) but step by step it will make more sense ...

Comment: If you haven't already you should also read up on Core Data as a solution for data storage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have skimmed through this topic, but to tighten the stuff I have read so far, playing around with this things in the first step. I do not have the aim to earn money with Apps ;) it is just for fun and to prove "I am able to do so" ;-) But after this displaying stuff, adding and editing of things will be the next, than Core Data will be relevant, I think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check for existing String with `[categorieTemp containsObject:tempString]` and sort it with `[categorieTemp sortUsingComparator:...]`

Example:

```
[categorieTemp sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    return [(NSString *)obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)obj2];
}];
```

Comment: Hi, I do not understand how containsObject should help. I would like to have a list with unique items (all categories only one time).

Comment: Before adding to the `categorieTemp` array you can check with `[categorieTemp containsObject:tempString]` if it was already added. Alternatively step through the array and check every String against the String to be added.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to sort my array for a date:

```
[array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate *date1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"datum"] == nil ? nilDate : [obj1 objectForKey:@"datum"];
        NSDate *date2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"datum"] == nil ? nilDate : [obj2 objectForKey:@"datum"];
        return (NSComparisonResult)[date2 compare: date1];
    }];
```